# Processing Multiple Files via oShell.Execute - Files NOT created

Tags: vbscript, cmd, gawk

What I am doing it copying files from a server to my local drive (fixed locations) and for a couple of these copied files I want the same command line script as in

```
CMD /c gawk -f ReduceFile.AWK W:\INPUTFILE.DAT > C:\DATA\QLD\OUTPUT
```

and then do it again

```
CMD /c gawk -f ReduceFile.AWK X:\INPUTFILE.DAT > C:\DATA\ACT\OUTPUT
```

The `awk` script is used to simply reduce the original file down (by terminating at a point where the data after is not important to me).

I'm copying and processing files via VBS and simply use an `oShell.Execute` to run a string variable command line of the above. In each case I set the variable and the run via `oshell.Execute`.

Executing this command more than once with different file inputs for different redirected file outputs. Sometimes the files get created with data and other times I get a zero file (there should be data all the time). I've tried getting VBS to sleep for XX seconds but flaky.

Do multiple `oShell.Execute` command get executed something like asynchronously?
Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I don't see it clear. Are you using `.Execute` or `.Exec` method? Do you need to run the commands asynchronously or you are trying to avoid it?

Comment: We can't debug your code without seeing your code.